# Inclusion probabilities in two stage cluster sampling

Tags: sampling, sample

So, there are H total clusters, each with size N_h.

Two-stage cluster sampling involves:
1. Randomly selecting n_1 <= H clusters (without replacement) 
2. Randomly selecting (w/o replacement) n_2 elements from each of the n1 clusters.

So, I want to calculate π_u = P(u is in the sample)

and

π_uv = P(u and v is in the sample) if u and v are in the same cluster
and π_uv if they are in different clusters